# collectionView Animates Color on Reload

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, reload

Whenever collectionView reloads, firstColor and secondColor mixes for a moment then get back to how they should be. For some reason adding gradient caused that problem. without gradient and with only one color this problem does not occur.

Here is the video link to the problem.  [Video](https://vimeo.com/739974295)

```
    extension PostSurveyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.surveyColors.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SurveyColorCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SurveyColorCollectionViewCell
        cell!.setup(surveyViewModel.surveyColors[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        for index in surveyViewModel.surveyColors.indices {
            self.surveyViewModel.surveyColors[index].isSelected = false
        }
        self.surveyViewModel.surveyColors[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

class SurveyColorCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var bigSquare: UIView!

let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
static let identifier = String(describing: SurveyColorCollectionViewCell.self)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
func setupGradient(_ survey: SurveyModel) {
    gradientLayer.frame = bigSquare.bounds
    bigSquare.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    let topColor: CGColor = survey.firstColor.cgColor
    let bottomColor: CGColor = survey.secondColor.cgColor
    gradientLayer.colors = [topColor, bottomColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    bigSquare.clipsToBounds = true
}

func setup(_ survey: SurveyModel) {
    bigSquare.layer.borderWidth = 1
    bigSquare.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray.cgColor
    bigSquare.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    
    self.setupGradient(survey)
}

    class SurveyViewModel {
    
    var surveyColors: [SurveyModel] = []
    
    func getSurveys() {
        surveyColors = [
            SurveyModel(firstColor: UIColor.white, secondColor: UIColor.white, isSelected: true),
            SurveyModel(firstColor: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 138/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 159/255, green: 0/255, blue: 73/255, alpha: 1), isSelected: false),
            SurveyModel(firstColor: UIColor(red: 19/255, green: 146/255, blue: 299/255, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 123/255, green: 0/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1), isSelected: false),
            SurveyModel(firstColor: UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 204/255, blue: 98/255, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 88/255, blue: 139/255, alpha: 1), isSelected: false)
        ]
    }
}

    struct SurveyModel {
    let firstColor: UIColor
    let secondColor: UIColor
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. Everything appears to hinge on SurveyModel (and in particular its `surveyColors` and related properties) but you have not shown that. Note, however, that for every cell on every reload you are adding the `gradientLayer` — even if the `gradientLayer` has _already_ been added to the cell. That is unlikely to give the result that you intend. Also, keep in mind that changing a CAGradientLayer's colors, start point, and end point _causes animation_ which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: added viewmodel and model. How can I create without changing their colors?